Can't convert file_id to media, Not an existing file, an HTTP URL or a valid bot-API-like file ID - TELETHON
How to use userbot in telegram to send a gif or sticker in TELETHON, i use send_file method and get an error "cant convert file_id to media, Not an existing file, an HTTP URL or a valid bot-API-like file ID"
I try to search every single document but can't find the answer

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
